# Which is the most general notion of convergence?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

If I have a topological space $(X,\tau)$ I can define a notion of convergence of a sequence (i.e. $x_n\to x$) based on neighbourhoods of $x$.
However do exists notions of convergence which do not come from a topology (a.e. convergence for example), so I wonder what could characterize the concept of convergence in an higher sense than the topological one.

Comment: Some more general (but still topological) notions of convergence are the convergence of a net and the convergence with respect to a filter.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Convergence_spaces (I have a strong feeling that this is an obsolete notion, though)

Comment: I think a better reference for convergence spaces is nLab: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convergence+space

Answer (score 0):

Given the notion of convergence on a set, you can define closed sets using sequences, and you get a topology. I hope this helps.

Comment: This is not true. For example, convergence almost everywhere is not topological.

Comment: @tomasz can you please elaborate?

Comment: @tomasz: It is, though. Just because the convergence isn't satisfied on all points doesn't mean it's not topological. You incorporate measure theory by allowing the topological convergence to fail on a set of measure zero.

Comment: @OpenBall: Consider a sequence $I_n$ of intervals in $[0,1]$ with diameter tending to $0$, such that each $x\in[0,1]$ is in infinitely many $I_n$. Let $f_n=\chi_{I_n}$. Then $f_n$ is not convergent almost everywhere, but it is convergent to $0$ in measure, so every subsequence of $f_n$ has a subsequence convergent almost everywhere to $0$ (this is fairly obvious in this case); in other words, $0$ is the only limit point of every subsequence of $f_n$. But in a topological space, every non-convergent sequence either has a subsequence without limit points, or it has more than one limit point.

Comment: @T.Eskin: I'm not saying it has nothing to do with any topology, just that there is no topology on the space of (equivalence classes of) functions such that convergence almost everywhere is exactly the convergence in this topology.

Comment: @tomasz thanks. This is quite insightful.

Comment: @tomasz given a notion of convergence, how does one prove that it generates a topology?

Comment: @OpenBall: In practice, I have no idea. In theory, I think you can use the notion to define a "closure operator" (note that it would need to be defined by taking recursively the limits of all possible nets, which is why I say "in theory", because practically this seems infeasible) and check if it satisfies the standard Kuratowski's axioms. And then I suppose you would need to check if the convergence in the topology you obtain agrees with the original one.

Comment: @tomasz I'll keep my answer because the discussion is useful.

Comment: There is a notion of convergence space (among which the a.e. convergence) and a subclass called the topological convergence spaces that come from a topology (it has one extra axiom about diagonal subnets or diagonal sequences). Kelly has a discussion IIRC. And Schechter's book too.